# Server or Gmail not passing through email with HTML

Tags: php, email, gmail

I just came across they weirdest problem. I suddenly can't send certain emails. Apparently I can't sent emails with html anymore. It has worked for a few years, but today it suddenly stopped working.

• Im using the php mail() function
• Using google apps MX records
• Sending email with just text works
• any html code doesn't work - link

When I'm sending from th server, does it even matter if we are using google apps?

What should i look in to? Server or google apps?

```
mail( 'me@hotmail.com', 'test', '<a href="test.com">test</a>', "From:domain<me@domain.com>" );
```

Comment: have you sent to multiple accounts on different hosting platforms.

Comment: yes, i have tried to send to hotmail, gmail and also to a different server within the same hosting company.